# Error for Authenticating SOAP API User when connect to Salesforce using POSTMAN

Tags: xml, postman, content-type

I need help resolving this issue.

1. I have created a POST callout out to the Salesforce URL: https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/50.0 with Postman.
2. I added the SOAP raw body under the *Body Tab* complete with my SF credentials.
3. I selected the XML option (and I notice that there is no “XML (text/html)” option anymore)
4. I unchecked the *default* Content-Type key under the Headers tab ( it was Read-Only and not letting me change the value to *“text/html”* from the default value of *“application/xml”*).
5. Added a *new* Content-Type key set to *“text/html”* under the Headers tab. Please see the last entry
6. Added the SOAPAction key under the Headers tab.
7. When I sent the Post method , I got a 500 response where the fault string tag indicated that “content-type of the request should be text/xml”

**Questions**: << I have listed screen shots below>>

1.Why is it returning this error when it seems like everything should be configured correctly?

2. Are there versions of Postman that still use the “text/html” option for the Body tab ?
   Currently only HTML, Text, JSON, JavaScript, and XML are the only selections but I have seen examples with “XML (text/xml)”.

<<Thanks . See scrapes below. (Note: Credentials have been falsified for security reasons)>>

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. change the method from Post to Get so that the Content-Type will be removed.

1B) Set the Body Tab to form-data.

2. In the Headers tab, add the new Content-Type as the key and add text/xml as the value.
3. Change the method back to Post and verify that the default Content-Type does not overwrite the one you just added in step 2.

3b) CHange Body Tab to raw.

4. Send your request and verify that you get a return code of 200 OK.
5. Check the response body which should give you your SF user instance and your User Info plust Server URL and Session ID.